# Disable text on input fields contact form 7 wordpress

Tags: wordpress, input, contact-form-7, input-field

I want to disable or erase the text of my input fields from my contact form.

Specially on the fields that appears text like "Full name", "Email Address" and "Your message will be here"

I am using Contact Form 7 of Wordpress and I configured spanish lenguage as default but it still in english this text.

Here is the link: http://crepali.com.mx/contacto/

How can I translate it or disable?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `placeholder` set on the form config?

Comment: I have tried using the placeholder but it doesn't work yet! :/

Comment: Did you try `[text text-7 placeholder ""]`? Or disabling other plugins/swapping themes?

Comment: I have tried with the placeholder on the form config only

Answer (score 32):

Use the word **readonly**
for example

```
[text text-859 readonly "1 Week Trial"]
```

i tried this and it worked

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
[text domainname  readonly]
```

Its working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a field read-only, set the readonly option in the form-tag like this:

1. ****strong text**Try this**

[text* your-name readonly class:required "Write your text here"]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`[text text-346 placeholder "nombre completo"]`

Comment: This answer worked for me using Contact Form 7, version 5.8.5.
Adding "placeholder" makes the text uneditable and disappear when the user starts typing something into the input field. Make sure that "placeholder" comes straight after the field name as in the example - putting it in the wrong position can disable it.

Using "readonly" makes it so the user cannot type anything into the input field.

Answer (score -2):

In wp-admin you have seen Contact Menu form here you create the contact form

Full Name is the placholder which you are seeing.

your code in the contact form 7 like following

```
[text text-346 placeholder "full name"]
```

Kindly remove the "placholder full name" text form the field

```
 [text text-346]
```

Comment: I have tried wit this feature and the text on the field doesn't change :/